# Want to get array of objects using json for ios5

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I had searched for complete googling. but found no answer for it.
I have the problem in parsing the array of objects from the json result .
I have json result like this:

> [{"created_at":"Sat Apr 28 13:36:24 +0000 2012",
>       "text":"@LisaPrejean  Love your work!  Very well done!",
>       "source":"web","user":{"id":478983313,"name":"3rd Dimension Media",
>       "created_at":"Mon Jan 30 21:51:20 +0000 2012","favourites_count":0},
>       "retweet_count":0}]

& from result i want etract only "created_at" & "text"

> - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
>     {
>          NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>          NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
>          self.jsonData = nil;
>
>   ```
>   NSArray *tweetArray = [jsonString JSONValue]; 
>    tweetTextArray = [NSMutableArray array];
>   for (NSDictionary *tweet in tweetArray)
>   ```
>
>   {
>           [tweetTextArray addObject:[tweet objectForKey:@"text"]];
>           [tweetCreated_atArray addObject:[tweet objectForKey:@"created_at"]];
>         }
>     }

but getting EXC_bad_access error on line:
NSArray *tweetArray = [jsonString JSONValue];

Comment: Have you looked at this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5)?

Comment: taken help from this example                                       http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json/

Comment: when i am assigning value to tweetArray application is crashing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil];
NSString *text = (NSString *) [data objectForKey:@"text"];
NSLog(@"textvalue= %@",text);
NSString * created_at = (NSString *) [data objectForKey:@"created_at"];
NSLog(@"created_at= %@",created_at);
```

Comment: getting error --" use of undeclared identifier 'pareser'; did you mean 'pause'?"

Comment: yes used from the below link:                                                                  https://github.com/stig/json-framework

Comment: import ur json header file like #import "JSON.h"